# Foundation Zurb 4 Top Bar Not Dropping Down

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 4 and my top bar navigation is not dropping down. I know my files are linking correctly, I'm not getting any console errors and my divs are falling into place when resizing my browser, which means my Foundation files are linked correctly. My top bar even collapses when I resize to a certain point, which is what I want.

The drop down menus don't work. Both when I collapse my nav and then click it to try and expand, nothing happens, and also when I just roll over my buttons nothing happens at all.

Head:

```
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
```

And Body

    
    
    Menu

```
<section class="top-bar-section">

  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
  <ul class="right">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown">
      <a href="#">Main Item 4</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="">Has Dropdown, Level 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Has Dropdown, Level 2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown test">
                <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">See all &rarr;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown">
      <a href="#">Main Item 6</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">See all &rarr;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Site can be viewed live here: http://upsuperiordesigntest.com/zurbTopbar1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `foundation/foundation.topbar.js` since 
`foundation.min.js` already contains the code for `foundation.topbar.js`

If you want to call these items separately, you should call 
`foundation/foundation.js` (not the min)  and `foundation/foundation.topbar.js`

Comment: Thank you, turns out all I needed to add was:     <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { $(document).foundation(); });
    </script>

before the closing body tag and it all worked. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

Beware, foundation.min.js  has all sets of parameters that are set-up in a peculiar way:

```
Foundation.libs.topbar={name:"topbar",version:"5.0.1",settings:{index:0,sticky_class:"sticky",custom_back_text:!0,back_text:"Back",is_hover:!0,mobile_show_parent_link:!1,scrolltop:!0}
```

I had to revert to using the separate files foundation + foundation.topbar to get it running properly.

Admittedly I cannot explain why the foundation.min file is set-up differently.